# Unhelpful (maybe wrong?) gcc error message

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, overload-resolution

I just spent a couple of hours debugging a compiler error that I could have fixed immediately if the compiler's error message had been more helpful.

I've reduced it to a simple example:

```
template <typename T>
int f(int);

template <typename U>
auto g(U x) -> decltype(f(x));

int main()
{
    g(0);
}
```

The error is:

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:9:8: error: no matching function for call to 'g(int)'
test.cpp:9:8: note: candidate is:
test.cpp:5:29: note: template<class U> decltype (f(x)) g(U)
```

Is this error not at best misleading and at worst, outright wrong? The way I see it, the problem is *not* that the given definition of g is not a match for the call, but that the definition is malformed (since in the expression f(x) in the decltype, it tries to call f without specifying f's template parameter).

Wouldn't a much more reasonable error message be something like:

```
no matching function for call to 'f(int)' in 'decltype(f(x))'
in instantiation of 'g(U)' with U = int
```

or even better:

```
failed to deduce template parameter 1 in call to 'f(int)' in 'decltype(f(x))'
in instantiation of 'g(U)' with U = int
```

I would have expected something like that...

Comment: Which version of GCC on which platform?  Is that a G++ extension or new-to-C++0x syntax?  Given the use of `auto`, I think the latter.

Comment: @Jonathan: The decltype and the late-specified return type are new to C++0x (hence the C++0x tag for this question). They have been supported by gcc since (at least) version 4.4. The error I quoted is produced by an experimental build of gcc 4.6, but 4.4 and 4.5 give similar errors.

Comment: GCC 4.5.2 compiled on MacOS X 10.6.6 compiling with `g++ -std=c++0x -c xx.cpp` gives the simpler - less informative - errors: `xx.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:` and `xx.cpp:9:8: error: no matching function for call to ‘g(int)’`.  I think that means you're using a different version of G++ - possibly a newer one.

Comment: @Jonathan: yes, 4.4 and 4.5 just say 'no matching function', only the experimental build of 4.6 mentions the candidate. My point is, even so it could be much more informative.

Comment: At this stage, my only suggestion is 'report to http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html'.  They've made improvements to the message between 4.5.2 and 4.6; maybe they can do more, still.

Comment: Does it help any to note that if you change the initial template to `template <typename T> int f(T);`, then the code compiles without error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely hitting the "extended SFINAE" rules in C++0x; since the call to `f(x)` is not working within the instantiation of the return type of `g` (because of the inability to deduce `T` for the call to `f`), `g` has an invalid return type and thus is removed from the overload set silently.  This is a feature, despite its harm to error message quality, because the compiler is assuming that `g` is an unrelated function that you aren't intending to call.  In this case, there are no other overloads of `g`, so the compiler should give a better message, though.

There is more information on extended SFINAE available at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2634.html.

Comment: What do you mean by "the compiler is assuming that g is an unrelated function that you aren't intending to call"?

Comment: I was trying to explain the reasoning behind the new SFINAE rules -- to prevent spurious errors from accidentally hitting an overload that wasn't meant to be called.  That reasoning doesn't apply in this case; the new rules make the error message worse without producing any benefit.

Answer (score 1):

With Clang I get this error

```
C:\Users\SUPER USER\Desktop>clang++ -cc1 -std=c++0x aa.cpp
aa.cpp:9:5: error: no matching function for call to 'g'
    g(0);
    ^
aa.cpp:5:6: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with U = int
]
auto g(U x) -> decltype(f(x)){}
     ^
1 error generated.
```

Much easier to understand than the error produced by g++